# meteor helper functions, lambdas and lexical this

Tags: javascript, meteor, lambda, ecmascript-6

g'day,
I read meteor was going all ecmascript 6 - and thought awesome... "I never have to write 'function' again" - so quickly changed a bunch of functions over to lambdas... only to discover it doesn't work :(

If you write a helper function in meteor - you get the data context passed in in the "this" property - but of course, lambdas use a lexical this - so I understand the problem pretty simply.

the thing is - what is not obvious to me is the solution - any idea how you would make a helper function using the () => notation that needs the current data context?   It doesn't seem to live anywhere other than "this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shorthand for defining functions as object properties:

```
Template.someTemplate.helpers({
  someHelper() {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

But if you really want to use `() =>` syntax, you may be interested in using `Template.currentData()` instead of `this`:

```
Template.someTemplate.helpers({
  someHelper: () => {
    console.log(Template.currentData());
  }
});
```

From [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata):

> **Template.currentData()**
>
> Inside a helper, returns the data context of the DOM node where the
>   helper was used.

Comment: awesome - thanks!   will give it a go.   The "function" keyword is what I dislike most about javascript - so getting it out of my life completely is a primary aim :)

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 2015 didn't deprecate `function()`. Arrow functions are ***not*** shorthand syntax, they have different semantics, most notably, lexical `this` binding.

You can't have a contextual `this` in an arrow function - use standard functions instead.

Comment: because the question was "given lexical this, how do you make meteor work" - and you said "it can't work, because of lexical this".   The other answer perfectly solved the problem.

Comment: @DarrenOakey - The way you phrased your question in the comment here is much clearer then what you used in the post itself, but you're correct - I can now see that this is what you meant. With that in mind, your interpretation of my answer ("*it can't work...*") is ***wrong***. My answer is that you shouldn't stop using `function()` just because arrow functions were introduced. These are 2 very similar, but not identical expressions, and both have pros & cons. I do agree with you that my answer is not meteor-specific, but I hope you can agree with me it is no less relevant or correct.