# Meteor data context within templates vs helpers

Tags: templates, meteor, helper

Trying to understand better how data contexts works in Meteor, as I can't figure out this problem I'm facing. Haven't found a clear answer anywhere. I have the following templates

```
<template name="list">
  {{#each listItem}}
    {{> listItemDetail}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="listItemDetail">
  <p>{{_id}} {{title}}</p>
  <p>{{idViaHelper}}</p>
</template>
```

And in my Javascript I have

```
Template.list.helpers({
    'listItem': () => {
        return List.find().fetch();
})

Template.listItemDetail.helpers({
    'idViaHelper': () => {
        return this._id
})
```

As far as my understanding of data contexts within Meteor goes, using `#each` sets the context for each instance of the `listItemDetail` template to be a document that that is returned from the `listItem` helper.

And this works as I'd expect when it comes to using `{{_id}}` in the `listItemDetail` template, showing the ID of the document.

But if I try to get the same `_id` via a helper `{{idViaHelper}}` which uses `this._id`, I get `undefined`. When I try `console.log(this)`, it shows me that `this` is referring to the Window object. But I have no idea why. What is going on and why does the data context not get picked up in the template helper?

This is my first post, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the Meteor datacontext flow.
What you are doing is working.

You only forget what the `this` represent into a lambda function.

Read the the part **Lexical this** from MDN, it's better explained than what I could say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

For your case, the easier way to get the datacontext directly from your this on helpers is to pass by usual anonymous function.

Just try:

```
Template.listItemDetail.helpers({
    'idViaHelper': function(){
        return this._id
})
```

That's it.

You've got unlucky on this one, there is no issue related to Meteor here.

Other related question you could find useful: [meteor helper functions, lambdas and lexical this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774105/meteor-helper-functions-lambdas-and-lexical-this)

Comment: Thanks Julien. I thought that arrow functions were purely a syntactical change in ES2015 (and the old way of declaring functions would be deprecated), but I guess if there is a technical difference and a use for both then maybe they'll both stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Julien Leray is correct in his answer regarding lexical `this`.  You lose the data context when using lambda expressions.  However, Meteor offers you ways to access your Template data without lexical `this`, viz.:

```
Template.list.helpers({
  'listItem': () => List.find().fetch();
});

Template.listItemDetail.helpers({
  'idViaHelper': () => Template.currentData()._id
});
```

You can use both `Template.currentData()` and `Template.instance().data`.

Also, note that if you have a lambda expression that only includes a single return statement, you can use the shortcut syntax as I did above.

```
// ECMAScript 5
var myFunc = function (a, b, c) {
  return b * a - c;
};
```

Becomes:

```
// ECMAScript 6
const myFunc = (a, b, c) => b * a - c;
```